# gitbook editor kaTex expected comma after expression

Tags: math, gitbook, katex

This is the error information:

[image]

The following is my book.json:

```
{
    "plugins": ["katex"]
}
```

The following is my error file:

[image]

I just can't figure out what's wrong with the math expression.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the math expression is ok, at least it works perfectly with KaTeX for browsers

```
$$S_{N_k}={{E(N_k-\mu_{N_k})^3 }\over {\sigma _{N_k}^3}}$$
```

I'm not familiar with gitbook, but I can suggest at least this: while you have

```
$$S_{N_k}={{E(N_k-\mu_{N_k})^3 }\over {\sigma _{N_k}^3}}$$,
```

it is usually suggested that the comma is inside the formula (may be gitbook requires that as a good practice), so try:

```
$$S_{N_k}={{E(N_k-\mu_{N_k})^3 }\over {\sigma _{N_k}^3}},$$
```